# getenv() is working in browser but not in command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line

On my server, I have an environement variable set to 'valueOfMyVariable'. My problem is that getenv() return false if I run the file in command line, but true if I run it from a browser.

`<?php var_dump( getenv('myEnvVariable') ) ?>`

Running this code from the command line ( `php myfilename.php`) will return `'false'`.

Running this code from a browser returns `'valueOfMyVariable'.`

I'm expecting from both call to have `'valueOfMyVariable'` as a result.

Does anyone know why in the first case, I have `false` instead of my variable ? Does that problem comes from a configuration problem ?

If I'm not clear enough feel free to ask for precision, the problem is simple but it's hard to explain it properly as English is not my main language.

Comment: One thing to check is the case of the variable.

Comment: @JasonK If you mean checking the variable in a switch case, by running the script in command line I always end up in the default case instead of the `getenv('myEnvVariable') == 'valueOfMyVariable'` case. It works properly from the browser.

Comment: Depending on the operating system getenv() is not always case insensitive. 'path' != 'PATH'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't export the environment variable in your terminal session.

```
export myEnvVariable=someValue
php myfilename.php
```

It's presumably working in the browser because the webserver is setting the environment variable.

Comment: It's working properly thanks. :) Is there a way to keep that on the server "memory" ? Otherwise each time I launch a ssh session I have to write again the export line.

Comment: No, that's not how environment variables work. The environment is a set of variables that you inherit from the calling process.

Comment: Does that means a file called from the server crontab won't have access to that environment variable either ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Environment variables are normally set in shell startup scripts like `.bashrc` or `.profile`. These scripts aren't run automatically by `cron`.

Comment: The usual procedure is to put variable settings in a PHP script that you load with `include` or `require`.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do then. Thanks a lot !